# Custom button on list view limitations

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a custom button on my accounts list view to change the record from the current owner to my ownership using OnClick Javascript. I have admin privileges and when I use the button it succeeds in changing the ownership to me. However, when I try to change the ownership as another user the record does not change ownership. I have ensured that the profiles of the users attempting to make the change have the system permission to change the record owner or transfer records. Any help is appreciated. The code used was as follows:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js')} 

var accountIds = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Account)}; 
var account = [], tempAccount, result; 

while(accountIds.length) { 
tempAccount = new sforce.SObject('Account'); 
tempAccount.Id = accountIds.shift(); 
tempAccount.OwnerId = '{!$User.Id}'; 
account.push(tempAccount); 
} 
result = sforce.connection.update(account); 
window.top.location.href = window.top.location.href;
```

Comment: you can try to output result to see what kind of errors are happening during update

Comment: please console.log(accountIds) and see what your values are..

Answer (score 0):

You probably have custom validation or trigger, which doesn't allow you to update record.

You could try to debug javascript errors if add after

```
result = sforce.connection.update(account);
```

This:

```
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
 if(result[i].getBoolean("success")){
  console.log("account updated with id"+result[i].id);
 }else{
  console.log("failed to update account"+result[i]);
  alert(result[i].errors.message);
 }}
```

You should see Alert and you can find full debug in browser console.

Comment: `{!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Account)}` returns Ids

Comment: I have empty array at custom list view page

Comment: Did you check some records? - these are going to be submitted.